# Do files at /etc/apt/sources.list.d need to have an extension '.list'?

Tags: configuration, apt, repository, software-sources, documentation

In `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` I have several files for custom repositories. All the names of those files end with `.list`.

Is it obligatory that files in that folder should end with that extension? If yes, where is that information written?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yes, names of files in `/etc/sources.list.d` must end in `.list` for lines in the files to be taken as specifying software sources that ought to be used. Otherwise, the files may be taken to have a different meaning.

**sources.list**

From [`man sources.list`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man5/sources.list.5.html) (1):

> NAME
>          sources.list - Package resource list for APT
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> The package resource list is used to locate archives of the package
>   distribution system in use on the
>          system. At this time, this manual page documents only the packaging system used by the Debian GNU/Linux
>          system. This control file is /etc/apt/sources.list.
>
> The source list is designed to support any number of active sources
>   and a variety of source media. The
>          file lists one source per line, with the most preferred source listed first. The format of each line
>          is: type uri args The first item, type determines the format for args.  uri is a Universal Resource
>          Identifier (URI), which is a superset of the more specific and well-known Universal Resource Locator,
>          or URL. The rest of the line can be marked as a comment by using a #.
>
> SOURCES.LIST.D
>
> The /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory provides a way to add
>   sources.list entries in separate files. The
>          format is the same as for the regular sources.list file. File names need to end with .list and may only
>          contain letters (a-z and A-Z), digits (0-9), underscore (_), hyphen (-) and period (.) characters.
>          Otherwise APT will print a notice that it has ignored a file if the file doesn't match a pattern in the
>          Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently configuration list - in this case it will be silently ignored...

**sources.list.save**

The `.list.save` files are some kind of work/backup files:

- http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=614398
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/611925

**Links:**

1. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 11):

As a complement to user26687's answer:

Yes, any file inside `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` must have a `.list` extension otherwise `apt` will print a warning message and ignore the file, *except* if file matches a pattern in apt's `Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently` option.

The `Software Sources` GUI creates a `.list.save` for *each* `.list` file it manages, as a kind of "backup" file. The LP bug 611925 mentioned is from 2010, when apt did not silently ignore `.save` files yet, and as such generated a lot of warnings.

This behavior was fixed in apt version `0.8.3ubuntu1` in 2010 for [LP bug 631770](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/631770):

```
apt (0.8.3ubuntu1) maverick; urgency=low

  * merged fixes from debian-sid
  * debian/rules:
    - put ubuntu-archive.gpg back into the package (LP: #620576)
  * apt-pkg/init.cc:
    - ignore ".distUpgrade" and ".save" files in sources.list.d
      (LP: #631770)
```

Since then such files are silently ignored by `apt` by default. You can see all such patterns with:

```
apt-config dump | grep Dir::Ignore-Files-Silently::
```

So files like `.save`, `.bak`, `.orig`, among others, are also accepted (and ignored) in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed add-on answer. Added a few tidbits I hadn't run across yet.

Answer (score 2):

They can also end with .sources if you are using deb822 format.

Comment: True. This was added in APT 1.1, and is used for example by the Wine project to distribute their Ubuntu packages.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned the problem you are having. But to answer your query there has to be one file at `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` for every repository, and there are often two. The required one will end with `*.list` and the optional one will end with `*.list.save` (this file is auto-generated by some GUI repository managers). The primary list, managed by the OS, is `/etc/apt/sources.list` and auxiliary lists can be added to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/your-custom-list-here.list`.

Comment: I'm not solving any particular problem, I'm just learning how repositories are working in ubuntu. I don't understand why there should 2 files (with the exact content) and why not to use them to add repos.

Comment: Somewhat misleading answer in several ways: First, `.list.save` files are *not* required, they are sort of backup files created by the `Software Sources` GUI, only the `.list` file is used by the `apt` system; Second, repositories *can* be added to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, but it's not recommended to do so (the OS handles it), so admins and packages are actually *encouraged* to play with `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: For any reader ... the answer has been edited, reflecting the points that @MestreLion raised.