# Installation Problem - Ignoring file - invalid extension in ubuntu 16.04(xenial)

Tags: 16.04, extension

Whenever I try to install some software or plugin or codec, i'm often getting this problem :

```
Ignoring file 'mono-xamarin.lit' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

Please help me with a solution.

Comment: In addition to the answer you were given, heres a short explanation.  Files that belong in sources.list.d/ have to end with the file extension .list.  More information can be found here.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/82825/do-files-at-etc-apt-sources-list-d-need-to-have-an-extension-list

Answer (score 1):

The solution is easy for you to achieve, rename the file in question to be a proper file or remove it. To rename it you can do the following command:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.lit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
```

Or for removing it

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.lit
```